# Swap mouse buttons in java application

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouse

I'm using a dynamic graphic library to display data. By clicking with the left button on a node, a window pops out displaying info about it. I would like to use the right button instead, which by now is used to move the node around (without the window popping out). The problem is: the graph listeners I'm using only respond to the left button. So the only solution I can think of is to swap the mouse buttons mapping on the java application. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Use [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) as per docs *This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed.*, specifically see [`mousePress(int button)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress(int)) and [`mouseRelease`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseRelease(int)). Thus on mouse clicked get which button was pressed and fire the opposite button click.

Comment: You mean like: get the mouse event on the JPanel, swap the button, and then send it to the graph listener? If so, the problem is that I'd have to "block" the graph listener, or both graph and JPanel would get the events.

Comment: Can you override the class in the graphic library that listens for the mouse events? If so, you should be able to override mousePressed or mouseClicked.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but can you use `MouseListeners` for right click, and than use `java.awt.Robot` to left click that? just a thought. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, sorry. I already solved this a long time ago and I forgot to post the answer: The library I'm using is graphstream, and I just needed to set the graph DefaultMouseManagerm (with overriden functions) which takes care of mouse clicks on the graph.